# Showing the volume using 3D Printing Toolbox

Tags: mesh, modifiers, optimization

I want to optimize the volume of the intersection of 4 cameras(not blender camera). I assume that the camera FOV(vertical:70.6 grad and horizontal:60 grad) is a mesh(pyramid with the same FOV angle). I can rotate the 4 of the cameras but I can't change the position of them. Now I put 3 Boolean modifiers on mesh 1 with the operation Intersect and the objects are the other 3 cameras. The Boolean modifier is good because we can rotate it real time without destroying the object. Now what I want to do is counting the volume of the intersection of all of them real-time(I see the volume changing as I rotate the camera. I am using 3D  Printing Toolbox with the Statistic button. Why wouldn't the volume change(always about 443) although I am making the intersection bigger or smaller. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a realtime statistic, it is only updated when you manually click the volume button.

So no you aren't doing anything wrong.